# There will always be a function such that $y_i=f(x_i)$ for all $i$ and $(x_i ,y_i) \in \Re^2$ (uniqued values)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

This trouble has come from if it always is possible to create a function that links two elements between two unique sets even if there is no natural relation between they both. (or samples from a continous distribution).

To be more formal take $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ and $Y=\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ to be the given real sets furthermore they both are unique sets that is $x_i \neq x_k$ for $i \neq k$, the same for $y_i$, so I'd like to proof, or verify, if there is a function $f$, wich depends only from $x$, such that $y_i=f(x_i)$ for all $i\in \{1,...,N\}$, If not I'd like know if it still can be possible to get a 'good' approximation for this ($|f(x_i)-y_i| \sim 0$).

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many such functions. Just define $f$ first at the $n$ points $x_i$ as $f(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$, and then join those points by any type of curve you want. If you want something nice and smooth you could choose $f$ to be the [interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) for your pairs of points.

Answer (score 1):

So there are many many such functions, but I think you are asking about whether there are "nice" functions (like polynomials). For example I could define a function just as
$$
f(x)
=
\begin{cases}
y_i, &\text{if  } x = x_i\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $$
and this is a perfectly good function. BUT, this function probably isnt what you wanted.

If you want something like a polynomial, it is always possible to construct a polynomial that looks like what you want. As another answerer said, you can use the interpolation polynomial.